# Time to find the largest element in a Linked list

Tags: search, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

I have an ordered linked list. I want to know the time to find the max element in both cases:

- If I maintain a tail pointer to the end of the linked list, and
- If I do not do so.

Answer (score 11):

**For ordered linked list:**

- `O(1)` if the list is ordered from max to min as the first one is already the max one.
- `O(n)` if the list is ordered from min to max, it will become `O(1)` if you further have the tail pointer. The reason is that the max element is the last one in the linked list. Thus you have to traverse to the tail (`O(n)`). On the other hand, this will be `O(1)` when you have the tail pointer, you just return what the tail pointer pointers to.

**For un-ordered linked list:**

- Always `O(n)` no matter you have the tail pointer or not. The reason is that, for an un-ordered lined list, you have to traverse (`O(n)`) each one to determine which one is the max. And it cannot help even with a tail pointer.

Comment: And O(n) if it's an unordered list, whether or not you have the tail pointer.

Comment: @keshlam Yes, you are right. Added it to the answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Would be nice if there were any kind of explanation, as OP is clearly clueless...